# What can I do with beer ruined by Chlorophenols

Tags: off-flavor

I made some beer and it is not nice. Ruined by Chlorophenols. So... is there *anything* I can do with it to make it usable in some form? I know it will not be drinkable but heck if I could clean the cooker with it that would be better than throwing it away :)

Comment: I removed my answer about distilling, because I don't know how volatile chlorphenols are. They might just carry over into the liquor. But I would really like know myself, I seem to have 50 similar bottles.

Comment: If chlorophenols are similar in volatility to other phenols, they would carry over to the distillate. Scotch whisky made with peated malt is [famous for its phenolic character](http://www.whisky-news.com/En/reports/Peat_phenol_ppm.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I made two batches that were almost certainly infected/affected by wild yeast (I was experimenting with culturing my own yeast from the dregs of Odell's St. Lupulin) and ended up with a distinct phenolic taste. The maddening thing was that I could taste what the beer was supposed to be right along side the off flavor ... and they were both really good beers, but that off flavor was still there. I had a lot of trouble trying to drink them, but I didn't have the heart to pour it all down the drain ... so my wife tried squeezing a lime wedge into one and pronounced it drinkable, "like a Dos Equis or Pacifico or something" she said. The phenolic flavor was still there when I tasted it, but it was significantly less off-putting. I still wasn't a fan, but my wife ended up polishing off both batches in this manner over the next couple months. Now those batches are gone, and I'm much more careful about culturing my own yeast.